# add dependentAssembly tag to web config without xmlns by manifest

Tags: xml, web-config, dotnetnuke, manifest

I have a **DotNetNuke** manifest that add `dependentAssembly` tag to web config like this:

```
<component type="Config">
  <config>
    <configFile>web.config</configFile>
    <install>
      <configuration>
        <nodes>

          <node path="/configuration/runtime/ab:assemblyBinding" action="update"
            targetpath="/configuration/runtime/ab:assemblyBinding[ab:dependentAssembly/ab:assemblyIdentity/@name='EntityFramework']"
            collision="ignore" nameSpace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" nameSpacePrefix="ab">

            <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
              <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="bin/EntityFramework-6.1.3/EntityFramework.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>

          </node>              

        </nodes>
      </configuration>
    </install>
    <uninstall>
      <configuration>
        <nodes>
          <!--Remove EF -->
        </nodes>
      </configuration>
    </uninstall>
  </config>
</component>
```

After execution of this manifest, a `dependentAssembly` node for `EntityFramework` will be added to web config, like this:

```
<dependentAssembly xmlns="">
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="bin/EntityFramework-6.1.3/EntityFramework.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This node has `xmlns=""` attribute but I want to add this node without `xmlns=""`. Is my code is wrong?

Comment: Hi Ali are you able to find the solution?I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh Hi, I still could not find a solution for it.But you can add this node in webconfig in code behind without changing manifest see [link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/232695/scope/posts/updating-webconfig-from-custom-module-package). This is not so good but it work properly.

Comment: Thanks @Ali for your suggestion.